# Creating wrapping tiles with html5?

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-ui

I would like to create a web app with tiles to display content- where the tiles are fixed width/height and they wrap horizontally.  Individual tiles can be clicked and then the view changes to display tiles for children of the clicked tile.  For example, first screen of tiles could be 'Schools' and when you select a school you see tiles for students that are in that school.

I'm using [angular kendo ui](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-06-24/announcing-angular-kendo-ui.aspx) with a web api service to retrieve data- goal is to have one tile per model.  But I'm not really sure how to go about this.  This is my first go with angular and kendo ui

Are there any packages that I should be looking at?  I saw [Metro JS](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs), but that seems to be more about live tiles than wrapping layout.  Lots of stuff for xaml/wpf, but nothing for html5.

Suggestions on general architecture or good tutorials that are relevant to what I want to do?